# How do I get Cache Inspector to work when running Apache Traffic Server as a Forward Proxy Cache

Tags: apache-traffic-server

When trying to use Cache Inspector on Apache Traffic Server (8.0.8) while configured for forward proxy caching it seems like it's triggering a recursion when mapping is turned off (required for forward proxy).

```
-sh-4.2$ curl -v "localhost/myCI"
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /myCI HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Multi-Hop Cycle Detected
< Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 18:55:01 GMT
< Server: ATS/8.0.8
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 346
< Age: 2
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Cycle Prohibited</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Cycle Prohibited</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Could not process your request for the document
because it would cause an HTTP proxy cycle.  Please check the URL and your
browser's proxy settings.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
```

my configs:

```
-sh-4.2$ traffic_ctl config diff
proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required has changed
        Current Value   : 0
        Default Value   : 1
proxy.config.reverse_proxy.enabled has changed
        Current Value   : 0
        Default Value   : 1
proxy.config.http.server_ports has changed
        Current Value   : 80
        Default Value   : 8080 8080:ipv6
proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_server_no_cache has changed
        Current Value   : 1
        Default Value   : 0
proxy.config.http.cache.heuristic_min_lifetime has changed
        Current Value   : 604800
        Default Value   : 3600
proxy.config.http.cache.heuristic_max_lifetime has changed
        Current Value   : 2592000
        Default Value   : 86400
proxy.config.net.connections_throttle has changed
        Current Value   : 3000
        Default Value   : 30000
proxy.config.http_ui_enabled has changed
        Current Value   : 1
        Default Value   : 0
proxy.config.http.cache.required_headers has changed
        Current Value   : 0
        Default Value   : 2
proxy.config.admin.user_id has changed
        Current Value   : <snipped>
        Default Value   : nobody
proxy.config.http.cache.enable_default_vary_headers has changed
        Current Value   : 1
        Default Value   : 0
```

note: this was occurring before I changed the port from 8080 to 80, I am pretty sure it is supposed to provide myCI on whatever is configured as the port.

note2: `traffic_ctl config diff` gives all non default config values.

Note3: Remote browser behavior matches localhost curl behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed a closing slash on my URL eg /myCI/ instead of /myCI